# usort won't work after merging to objects

Tags: php, object, usort

I have the following code:

```
$content->Vehicles = (object)array_merge((array)$content->List, (array)$content_new->List);
```

The `$content->List` and `$content_new->List` are created from two API calls and is all working as expected.

The problem is I need to sort the object. To do so I use:

```
usort($content->Vehicles, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a->Score < $b->Score) ? -1 : (($a->Score > $b->Score) ? 1 : 0);
});
```

When I pass in `$content->List` it works as expected however `$content->Vehicles` results in `usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`.

Would love to figure this one out.

Comment: Sort the array, not the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fell silly now. Answer as follows:

```
$content->Vehicles = array_merge((array)$content->List, (array)$content_new->List);
```